# golang/apache/cgi on debian --- apache redirects stopped working

Tags: apache, go, url-rewriting, cgi

after a reinstall due to a hd crash my redirects have stopped working. Why? The only difference I can see is the root directory changed from var/www to var/www/html. I've tried specifying /var/www as the root along with /var/www/ for the directory. My default conf has the same directives if I turn ssl off I get the same issue.

I am using ssl and my 000-default-le-ssl.conf contains

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot   / var/www/html
<Directory  /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.yellowrockonline.com.au [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =yellowrockonline.com.au

 RewriteRule ^(wiki)$ https://www.yellowrockonline.com.au/cgi-bin/mywikicgi 
 RewriteRule ^(view/.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L] 
 RewriteRule ^(edit/.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L] 
 RewriteRule ^(save/.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

</Directory>

# Redirect "/view/suggestion" http://localhost:8080/view/suggestion 
# works but returns localhost:8080/ to the browser 
The cgi program starts from a link to www.domainname/cgi-bin/programname and returns domainma,e/view/suggestion to the browser along with the error
```

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at www.yellowrockonline.com.au Port 443

The link to the cgi program https://www.yellowrockonline.com.au/cgi-bin/mywikicgi

The go code that delivers the changed url

```
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/view/suggestion", http.StatusFound) 
    // added to do redirect
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello from Go!  Redirecting to suggestions")

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/view/", makeHandler(viewHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/edit/", makeHandler(editHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/save/", makeHandler(saveHandler))

   http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
   cgi.Serve(nil)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure out the difference between my old and my new configuration.  I finally remembered the first time I tried to do this I tried to use proxypass and not rewrite rules.

Once I enable proxypass the problem fixed itself its now working.  Though why this should be the case I've no idea I am not using proxy pass and rewrite should not be dependent upon it.

sudo a2enmod proxy && sudo a2enmod proxy_http

Guess what!  It fixed the problem and it now works!  I am happy again!

I've added an extra redirect to stop people seeing the name of the cgi-program thats running.